# ADSI LDAP query for Remote Desktop Users

Tags: active-directory, adsi, active-directory-group

I am trying to figure the ADSI query to get the list of users added to the group `Remote Desktop Users` in an AD domain.

I guess I need to set the appropriate filter to get the result.

I tried something like

```
(&(objectClass=Remote Desktop Users)(objectCategory=person)
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group membership is determined by the `memberOf` attribute - not `objectClass`.

You should try something like this:

```
(&(memberOf="cn=Remote Desktop Users")(objectCategory=person))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. (&(memberOf=CN=Remote Desktop Users,CN=Builtin,DC=MYDC,DC=COM)(objectCategory=person))